# Guava CacheBuilder doesn't call removalListener immediately after cache expiry

Tags: java, caching, guava

From my application logs, I feel like removeListener is not called immediately after the cache key is expired. This is creating a problem in the below scenario

Cache configuration:

```
SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
GuavaCache cache = new GuavaCache("cacheData", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).removalListener(expiredCacheListener()).build());
```

In the application logic, I see that when the `cache.get(key)` is called then if there is no value(because the cache is expired because of `expireAfterAccess()` method time limit) then it puts a new value in the cache for the same key since the old key is expired/removed.

After this write operation then immediately, I think that the removalListener is calling the `expiredCacheListener()` method which has the logic of changing the value for the expired key....  //But this is actually changing the new value!!!

Now I have a valid key with an incorrect value in the cache

If a thread is able to make a key as expired then shouldn't the same thread call the removalListener immediately? How can I solve this?

Comment: you can share code using `https://codeshare.io/` in realtime if needed

Answer (score 3):

That's just how Guava Cache works, see [CachesExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen):

> When Does Cleanup Happen?
>
> Caches built with `CacheBuilder` do not perform cleanup and evict values
> "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of
> the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during
> write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are
> rare.

Read more to know that Guava creators "put the choice in your hands"; you're free to maintain cleanup threads by yourself.

For more advanced `Cache` use cases use [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), which "provides an in-memory cache using a Google Guava inspired API." [Removal](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Removal) wiki page mentions that for synchronous removal listeners you could use [`CacheWriter`](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer).

Comment: Is it possible for me to do a check manually somehow to verify whether the `expired` key is overridden with new value or not in my `expiredCacheListener()` method? By the time the `removeListner()` is invoked, the cache key is having a new value so the removeListener() logic should not be applied on the key since it should not be considered as an expired key anymore

Comment: Is it possible to get the list of expired keys present in the cache (before I manually do a `cleanUp()` I want to check this)?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter "By the time the removeListner() is invoked, the cache key is having a new value so the removeListener() logic should not be applied on the key since it should not be considered as an expired key anymore"  This isn't how the cache works.  The removal listener will only be called on the old value that got actually removed; it will not be called on the newly computed value.  There is nothing special you need to do here.